# Why does my call to winapi RegisterClassExW fail (using JNA)?

Tags: java, winapi, jna

These are the winapi methods

```
ATOM WINAPI RegisterClassEx(
     _In_ const WNDCLASSEX *lpwcx
  );

typedef struct tagWNDCLASSEX {
  UINT      cbSize;
  UINT      style;
  WNDPROC   lpfnWndProc;
  int       cbClsExtra;
  int       cbWndExtra;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HICON     hIcon;
  HCURSOR   hCursor;
  HBRUSH    hbrBackground;
  LPCTSTR   lpszMenuName;
  LPCTSTR   lpszClassName;
  HICON     hIconSm;
} WNDCLASSEX, *PWNDCLASSEX;
```

My Java Code:-

```
public class WNDCLASSEX extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
    public int cbSize;
    public int style;
    public WNDPROC lpfnWndProc;
    public int cbClsExtra;
    public int cbWndExtra;
    public HMODULE hInstance;
    public HICON hIcon;
    public HCURSOR hCursor;
    public HBRUSH hbrBackground;
    public String lpszMenuName;
    public String lpszClassName;
    public HICON hIconSm;
}

public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    Atom RegisterClassExW(WNDCLASSEX wc);
}

public class other {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      User32.WNDPROC WndProc = new User32.WNDPROC() {

         public LRESULT callback(HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
         {
            int id = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, null);
            return new LRESULT(0);
         }
      };
      WNDCLASSEX wc = new WNDCLASSEX();
      wc.style = 0;
      wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
      wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
      wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
      wc.hInstance = null;
      wc.hIcon = null;
      wc.hbrBackground = null;
      wc.cbSize= wc.size(); 
      wc.lpszMenuName = null; 
      wc.lpszClassName = "Magnifier";


    Atom atom = User32.INSTANCE.RegisterClassExW(wc);
  }
}
```

I got the following error if I call `RegisterClassEx(wc)` method. I think the problem is due to `wc` is a object but `RegisterClassExW` accepts pointer.

If it is the case, How to send `wc` as pointer?
Else How can I solve this issue?

Error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument type jna.extra.WNDCLASSEX at parameter 0 of function RegisterClassExW

Comment: Where is your error message?

Comment: @Jan I have updated question.

Comment: Well, what does `User32.INSTANCE.RegisterClassExW` expect for its parameter? The error message could not be clearer.

Comment: It's disappointing that you posted fake code originally. Please learn from that.

Comment: Also, your window procedure is totally broken, so failure awaits there. Call DefWndProc. And you've given your window class a name that is used by a built in class. You must not register the Magnifier class. The system registers that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are correct but if I create a window with classname `Magnifier` it is giving `1407` error. That's why I am registering the class

Comment: Do you want help or not? Or do you think you are better off making it up as you go along? It's not much fun on this end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84764/discussion-between-vishnu-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: Did you build a C++ sample project yet? Start there. Try to learn JNA (or pinvoke) and Win32 and magnifier API at the same time is counter productive. You need a firm grasp of Win32 first. Then learn magnifier API. Then learn JNA. Then piece it together. Slowly. At the moment you are over-reaching.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In c++ if I create a window with `Magnifier` class it is working fine without even registering class but in JNA it is not working.

Comment: So you need to isolate the difference. Are you making the exact same sequence of calls?

Comment: Solved the issue. I have unintentionally commented `MagInitialize()` function. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WNDCLASSEX` needs to extend `Structure`, and then you'll need to implement its `getFieldOrder()` method.

```
public class WNDCLASSEX extends com.sun.jna.Structure {
    public int cbSize;
    public int style;
    public WNDPROC lpfnWndProc;
    public int cbClsExtra;
    public int cbWndExtra;
    public HMODULE hInstance;
    public HICON hIcon;
    public HCURSOR hCursor;
    public HBRUSH hbrBackground;
    public String lpszMenuName;
    public String lpszClassName;
    public HICON hIconSm;
    public List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("cbSize","style","lpfnWndProc","cbClsExtra","cbWndExtra","hInstance","hIcon","hCursor","hbrBackground","lpszMenuName","lpszClassName","hIconSm");
    }
}
```

Comment: The user hasn't posted the real code because the user is calling a `size()` method in their class. Presumably the real code already looks like yours. We need to persuade the asker to fix the question.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that.  @vishnu, please update your question.

Comment: @technomage thanks that worked but how to know whether the class it registered successfully. Because RegisterClassExW() function returns an `ATOM` but if I use that to create window it is showing `1407` (Cannot find window class.) error.

Comment: The documentation for RegisterClassEx describes how failure is reported.

Comment: I have done that. If I print the getLastError() it is showing `0` as response. Which means there is no error

Comment: You have to check the return value rather than call GetLastError. Anyway, this is the answer to the question that you asked. Your subsequent problems are many and varied and it's not fair to expect them to be provided in this answer. Please accept this answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will accept the answer. I have checked the return value, It returned an ATOM that means a success but If I create a window with that classname it is showing 1407 error. Just want to know the reason.

Comment: You mean it returned a non-zero value? Reason probably the duplicate name. Anyway, as I said in comments above, this is all wrong anyway. You've simply got to go back to basics and get on top of them first. And do it in C++ please.